# Swift -Property inside collectionView cell isn't updating after collectionView.performBatchUpdates > reloadItems(at:) runs

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView cell that has an `isExpanded: Bool` property. When the cell first loads it is set to `false` and it only shows 1 line of text. If the text is several lines long I append "more ..." to the end of the first line and if the label is pressed I expand the cell. It works but I have to press the label twice to expand the cell and then twice again to collapse the cell back to 1 line.

What I've come to find out is when I first press the label I check to see if `isExpanded == false` and if it is I set it to `true` then pass the cell's index.item back in a protocol and call `performBatchUpdates` and then `collectionView.reloadItems(at:)`.

After it runs I check `isExpanded` and instead of it being `true` it's `false` so the cell doesn't expand. If I press the label again now everything works the way it supposed to and the `isExpanded is true` and the cell expands.

Why do does the `isExpanded` property get set to `false` on the first go around even though I set it to true but on the second go around it stays set to true?

For a little more clarity

1. `isExpanded` is initially `false`
2. the label is tapped and `isExpanded` gets set to `true`
3. after `performBatchUpdates` and `reloadItems(at:)` runs `isExpanded` somehow gets set back to `false` (**this is the problem**)
4. after pressing the label once again `isExpanded` gets set to `true`
5. after `performBatchUpdates` and `reloadItems(at:)` runs once again `isExpanded` is `true` (**this is what should happen on the 3rd step**).

It should be a 3 step process but it's always a 5 step process.

When collapsing the cell the same thing happens and I have to press the label twice for it to collapse.

Cell Class

```
protocol: MyCellDelegate: class {
    func expandOrCollapseCell(indexItem: Int)
}

weak var delegate: MyCellDelegate?
var indexItem: Int = 0
var isExpanded = false

var review: Review? {
    didSet {
        if let review = review else { return }

        // run logic to expand or collapse cell depending on wether isExpanded is true or false
    }
}

func tapGestureForLabel() {

    if !isExpanded {

       isExpanded = true

    } else {

       isExpanded = false

    }

    delegate?.expandOrCollapseCell(indexItem: self.indexItem)
}
```

And inside the class with the CollectionView

```
func expandOrCollapseCell(indexItem: Int) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: indexItem, section: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0) {

        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ [weak self] in

           self?.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
           self?.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

    }) { (_) in
        print("finished updating cell")
       }
    }
}
```

I tried passing `isExpanded` in the protocol (I removed it) and inside the class with the CollectionView I updated the cell's `isExpanded` property like this but it made no difference

```
func expandOrCollapseCell(indexItem: Int, isExpanded: Bool) {

    if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCell {

        cell.isExpanded = isCellExpanded
    }

    // perform batchUpdates ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem of relying to the cell which is dequeued to hold a model state like

```
var isExpanded = false // should be inside model of each cell
```

you need to add this data to the model of the cell and check it when you need to change the state , then make the reload

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I was actually thinking that earlier but thought I was doing something wrong. I’ll add it in a few and get back to you with an update.